# Changing the title of individual plots within a panel of traceplots in ggplot2/rstan to greek letters with subscript

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I create traceplots of my stanfit objects via mcmc_trace.
I want to rename the titles of the traceplots.
I already managed to change the title, but I don't know how I can rename the plots to greek letters with subscripts similar to the expression function.

```
array <- as.array(fit)
array[1,1,1:3]
dimnames(array)[[3]][1:3] <- c("alpha1", "alpha2", "alpha3")

trace <- mcmc_trace(array, pars = c("alpha1", "alpha2", "alpha3")
```

I want to replace alpha1 with expression(gamma[0]), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try wrapping your titles like this:
'$\\gamma_0$'

Comment: Then $\\gamma_0$ is the title.

Comment: When you replace alpha1 with expression(gamma[0]) what is the output?

Comment: If I use the following code:

    array <- as.array(fit)
    array[1,1,1:3]
    dimnames(array)[[3]][1:3] <- c(expression(gamma[0]), "alpha2", "alpha3")

    trace <- mcmc_trace(array, pars = c("gamma[0]", "alpha2", "alpha3"))

I get gamma[0].
I can't write expression in the pars argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a little digging, it simply seems like `bayesplott::mcmc_trace` doesn't have an option for greek lettering.

However, the much similar `mcmcplots::traplot` package has an option `greek = TRUE`. 
I did a random example for you to see:

```
library(mcmcplots)

nc <- 3; nr <- 1000
pnames <- c(paste('alpha[', 1:2, ']', sep = ''), paste('gamma[1]', sep = ''))
means <- rpois(10, 20)
fakemcmc <- coda::as.mcmc.list(
  lapply(1:3, function(i) coda::mcmc(matrix(rnorm(nc*nr, rep(means, each=nr)),
                                            nrow=nr, dimnames=list(NULL,pnames)))))
traplot(fakemcmc, greek = TRUE)
```

Which produces this output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it! My problem is, that I don't know how to change the dimnames without the array function. And I can't use an array for traplot.

Comment: if x is a data.frame fx you can change it's names by doing `names(x) <- c('name1', 'name2')`

Comment: It's not so easy to change the names of a stanfit object. But the traplot function has the argument "main". With this new titles can be specified.